# MDAC Error on Windows XP - Deploy Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, clickonce, mdac

I am trying to deploy a VB.Net application using the built in Click Once.

When a User tries to install the application they receive the following error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0ayB.png

The machines they are trying to install to are Windows XP SP3 so I cant understand why I am getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following steps:

1. Compile your program and copy the whole bin\Release folder (output directory) to the target system. Does your program run if it's not distributed via ClickOnce?
2. Build a simple *"Hello World!"* program and distribute it via ClickOnce. Can this basic app be installed on the target system by running the ClickOnce installer?
3. Even though this should not be a problem on any system running a later Version of Windows than Win2k, have your tried to just install [Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.8 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5793)?

By doing so, you should be able to determine if your issue is either **ClickOnce**- or **Application**-related.

Comment: I have tried to run the Application without ClickOnce and i am still getting the same error.

It appears that the OLEDB connection is the problem. Like you said, this shouldnt be an issue on anything after Win2k. So im not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried to install MDAC (just to eiminate a possibile source for your error)? Is the basic *"Hello World!"* Application able to run? Or maybe you could use another dataprovider?